# Show buttons randomly by pressing them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, arc4random

I want to have six buttons in my project and want them to be always hidden except one. And when I press the button that is not hidden it should be hidden and another button should randomly appear and do the same. 
Would appreciate if someone could help me!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create six `buttons` in your Storyboard, add a tag to them and then create one `Action outlet` that you connect all buttons to and then do  the following:

```
@IBAction func button_clicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // generate a random number which is not the same as the tag that you 
    repeat{
        random = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
    }
    while random == sender.tag

    // iterate through all subviews in your view to find all buttons
    for view in self.view.subviews{
        // make sure it´s a button
        if view.isKind(of: UIButton.self){
            // create a button from the view you're iterating to
            let button = view as! UIButton
            // if the button tag is equal to the random number you just created we want to show that button 
            if button.tag == random{
                button.isHidden = false
            }
            // else hide it
            else{
                button.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2TR9xoKqvZNMDZqaEtUdk1SU28) is a sample project I created that does this that you can try. Make sure though to read the comments in the code above and understand what´s happening.

Comment: Thanks man that works for me! But when I add some more buttons in my project are they disappearing too by pressing one of the six buttons. How can I fix that?

Comment: I added this code into my project to hide every button except one. Is that ok? override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        BT6.isHidden = true
        BT5.isHidden = true
        BT4.isHidden = true
        BT3.isHidden = true
        BT2.isHidden = true
        //Hiding all but one button when the view controller loads
    }

Comment: You need to do 2 things: 1: Drag them to the button action from the storyboard to the `@IBAction func button_clicked(_ sender: AnyObject)` 2: add a tag in the storyboard

Comment: how can I add tags?

Comment: In your storyboard, click on the button and then on the right menu go to the Attribute inspector and you´ll see it under the view section.

Comment: every button the same tag?

Comment: No each button +1 so if the last button had 6, the next one should have 7. This is a unique tag to identify the button.

Comment: When I do this the buttons that should not disappear, disappear nevertheless. And the buttons 1-6 disappear after pressing one of them.

Comment: Could you please implement the two additional buttons in your sample project. I tried every possibility I know so far and they are always disappearing...

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2TR9xoKqvZNYlBZVmJNUTJ1dHc) is a link with 8 buttons @JuliIchSelber

Comment: Thank you for the help again but that is not what I meant. I want the 2 additional buttons to be always visible, because when I put just two more buttons in the project and tap one of the 6 buttons, the additional two buttons disappear and I don't know why.

Comment: So you want to show button 7 and 8 all the time? What shall happen when you press them?

Comment: Yes exactly. When I press one of the buttons 1-6, buttons 7 and 8 are going to disappear somehow... They should just have a simple action nothin special.

Comment: Buttons 7-8 should not be involved in disappearing and appearing in the view.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Fy-XZQl_vEOHROQ3Mwc1F5MG8 that is what actually happens

Comment: @JuliIchSelber, in the `for` loop where you check the buttons skip the new created tags. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2TR9xoKqvZNWVhiZkhOQVFSclk) is an updated project. Good luck.

Comment: But now buttons 7 and  8 make buttons 1-6 move. I want them to have a completely different action.

Comment: Just right click on them in the storyboard and remove the action

Comment: Do you know how to add a minus and a "-" and a "." button to a Number Pad Keyboard?

Comment: Do you know how to add a "-" and a "." button to a Number Pad Keyboard? @Rashwan L

Comment: Unfortunately not @JuliIchSelber

Answer (score 2):

**UI(storyboard)**
[image]

In my case, button tag number for six button is each assigned from 0 to 5.

[image]

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  StackOverflow
//
//  Created by Seoksoon Jang on 2016. 10. 1..
//  Copyright © 2016년 Seoksoon Jang. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var buttonTagNumberArray : Array<Int>?
var randomIndex : Int?

@IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var button6: UIButton!

@IBAction func button1Action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonTagNumberArray!.count)))

    if (randomIndex! == button1.tag) {
        button1Action(button1)
    } else {

        button1.isHidden = true

        switch randomIndex! {
            case button1.tag :
                print("it should happen : \(button1.tag)")
                break
            case button2.tag :
                button2.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button3.tag :
                button3.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button4.tag :
                button4.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button5.tag :
                button5.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button6.tag :
                button6.isHidden = false;
                break
            default:
                //
                break;
            }

        return ;
    }
}

@IBAction func button2Action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonTagNumberArray!.count)))

    if (randomIndex! == button2.tag) {
        button2Action(button2)
    } else {

        button2.isHidden = true;

        switch randomIndex! {
            case button1.tag :
                button1.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button2.tag :
                print("it should happen : \(button2.tag)")
                break
            case button3.tag :
                button3.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button4.tag :
                button4.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button5.tag :
                button5.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button6.tag :
                button6.isHidden = false;
                break
            default:
                //
                break;
        }

        return ;
    }

}

@IBAction func button3Action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonTagNumberArray!.count)))

    if (randomIndex! == button3.tag) {
        button3Action(button3)
    } else {

        button3.isHidden = true;

        switch randomIndex! {
            case button1.tag :
                button1.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button2.tag :
                button2.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button3.tag :
                print("it should happen : \(button2.tag)")
                break
            case button4.tag :
                button4.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button5.tag :
                button5.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button6.tag :
                button6.isHidden = false;
                break
            default:
                //
                break;
        }

        return ;
    }

}

@IBAction func button4Action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonTagNumberArray!.count)))

    if (randomIndex! == button4.tag) {
        button4Action(button4)
    } else {

        button4.isHidden = true;

        switch randomIndex! {
            case button1.tag :
                button1.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button2.tag :
                button2.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button3.tag :
                button3.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button4.tag :
                print("it should happen : \(button2.tag)")
                break
            case button5.tag :
                button5.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button6.tag :
                button6.isHidden = false;
                break
            default:
                //
                break;
            }

        return ;
    }

}

@IBAction func button5Action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonTagNumberArray!.count)))

    if (randomIndex! == button5.tag) {
        button5Action(button5)
    } else {

        button5.isHidden = true;

        switch randomIndex! {
            case button1.tag :
                button1.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button2.tag :

                break
            case button3.tag :
                button3.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button4.tag :
                button4.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button5.tag :
                print("it should happen : \(button2.tag)")
                break
            case button6.tag :
                button6.isHidden = false;
                break
            default:
                //
                break;
        }

        return ;
    }

}

@IBAction func button6Action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonTagNumberArray!.count)))

    if (randomIndex! == button6.tag) {
        button6Action(button6)
    } else {

        button6.isHidden = true;

        switch randomIndex! {
            case button1.tag :
                button1.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button2.tag :
                button2.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button3.tag :
                button3.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button4.tag :
                button4.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button5.tag :
                button5.isHidden = false;
                break
            case button6.tag :
                print("it should happen : \(button2.tag)")
                break
            default:
                //
                break;
        }

        return ;
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    buttonTagNumberArray = [button1.tag, button2.tag, button3.tag, button4.tag, button5.tag, button6.tag]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}    // class end
```

Comment: all I just wanted to use was recursion. :p

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have put your six buttons onto your storyboard and linked them into your class.
I did this pretty quickly so it's probably not the most efficent way.

You would want your class' code to look something like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    BT6.isHidden = true
    BT5.isHidden = true
    BT4.isHidden = true
    BT3.isHidden = true
    BT2.isHidden = true
    //Hiding all but one button when the view controller loads
}

@IBOutlet weak var BT6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BT5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BT4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BT3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BT2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var BT1: UIButton!

@IBAction func BT6(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    //this checks when BT6 is pressed and then hides it
    BT6.isHidden = true
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
    if random == 0 {
        BT5.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 1 {
        BT4.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 2 {
        BT3.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 3 {
        BT2.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 4 {
        BT1.isHidden = false
    }
    //this part creates a randomiser between 0-4 and depending on which number turns out, it will hide a certain button
}
@IBAction func BT5(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    BT5.isHidden = true
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
    if random == 0 {
        BT6.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 1 {
        BT4.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 2 {
        BT3.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 3 {
        BT2.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 4 {
        BT1.isHidden = false
    }
}
@IBAction func BT4(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    BT4.isHidden = true
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
    if random == 0 {
        BT5.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 1 {
        BT6.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 2 {
        BT3.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 3 {
        BT2.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 4 {
        BT1.isHidden = false
    }
}
@IBAction func BT3(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    BT3.isHidden = true
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
    if random == 0 {
        BT5.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 1 {
        BT4.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 2 {
        BT6.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 3 {
        BT2.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 4 {
        BT1.isHidden = false
    }
}
@IBAction func BT2(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    BT2.isHidden = true
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
    if random == 0 {
        BT5.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 1 {
        BT4.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 2 {
        BT3.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 3 {
        BT6.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 4 {
        BT1.isHidden = false
    }
}
@IBAction func BT1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    BT1.isHidden = true
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))
    if random == 0 {
        BT5.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 1 {
        BT4.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 2 {
        BT3.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 3 {
        BT2.isHidden = false
    } else if random == 4 {
        BT6.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot!